# How to restrict facebook usage to just sharing content on a museum/science center kiosk station

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, popup, kiosk, restrictions

so we set up some installations in a science center, where the end results are images and videos, which are uploaded to a server which is available from the outside (web).  From one certain kiosk station the users can browse through their material and are supposed to be able to share directly to their facebook page.  We got this working with the current working API, and the login popup shows up, people can log in and then it gets shared.

Our problem is that the login popup box also has some unwanted features, which enables you to end up inside the facebook system itself.  This is not good for the center as they don't want this to become a web browsing station.

So, my question is : how would I be able to allow people to log in and share specific content without allowing them to browse further and further into the facebook site?  Can I cover up the "about" links in the popup box, or in some other way work around the matter?

Thanx for any suggestion.

Comment: I also would like to mention that the installations are in Adobe Air, still using the official facebook graph API, which forces through the html popup for login.  As said before, this would be fine, if it didn't have linking further into the facebook site.  Also, let me add that logging in and the sharing of data does indeed work perfectly.  The problem is in restricting further use.

Comment: Just a thought: Is it possible to give access to certain urls. May be login and Authorize url while blocking the rest through proxy or browser itself. If you are using firefox or chrome may be a plugin can be used.